# Does the photoelectric effect require a battery or a circuit?

Tags: photoelectric-effect

This is how the professor showed us the photoelectric effect:

[image]

Does the photoelectric effect require:

a. a battery? what happens if the battery is replaced with a wire?

b. a circuit? what happens if it were the two metal plates only?

c. two metal places? what happens if it were a single metal plate only?

Comment: I get the feeling you don't actually know what the photoelectric effect is

Comment: ["*The photoelectric effect is the observation that many metals emit electrons when light shines upon them.*"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect). Nothing more. Nothing less.

Comment: So what's the point of the setup above? The circuit, the two metal plates and the battery are just for the voltage to find the stopping potential?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ACuriousMind says
"The photoelectric effect is the observation that many metals emit electrons when light shines upon them."  You don't need anything except the light and one plate for the photoelectric effect.  Why are the other parts there?  You presumably want to measure some things to understand the effect.  Having the circuit allows you to measure the photoelectric current as you change the illumination.  You will discover that the current is proportional to the brightness.  You can also vary the wavelength of the light and discover that there is a threshold wavelength, above which there is no photoelectric effect because the photons do not have enough energy to drive off the electrons.  The (variable battery-more likely a power supply) can be used to measure the maximum emission energy of the electrons.  This, coupled with changing the wavelength of the light, can show the proportionality between frequency and photon energy.

Answer (score 0):

The electric field of the "battery" allows you to measure the kinetic energy of the electrons, which is crucial for the understanding of the photoelectric effect, since that energy varies with the frequency of the light.